# javascript create/remove iframe causes memory leak in IE 9

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

When I click create button, memory usage does not increase much, but when I click destroy button memory consumption increases. The memory never gets reclaimed.  I guess it is a memory leak situation.

**javascript functions:**

```
    function create() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var y = document.createElement('iframe');
            y.id = 'dtest' + i;
            document.getElementById('iframeContainer').appendChild(y);
            y = null;
        }
    }

    function destroy() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('dtest' + i);
            iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
            iframe = null;
        }
    }
```

**html part:**

```
<div>
    <button id="create" onclick="create();return false;">Create Iframe</button>
    <button id="destroy" onclick="destroy();return false;">Destroy Iframe</button>
</div>

<div id="iframeContainer" style="background-color: Green">
</div>
```

Any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you just set iframeContainer's html to "" instead of removing the iframe?

Comment: @malonso there isn't any difference. Same as iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);